# Df is sorted but plotly x axis is not in order

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I am graphing a few df and I sorted them before graphing, but in the graph the x axis is not in order. Shown in the pic below

[image]

My code is here:

```
     fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                shared_xaxes=True,
                vertical_spacing=0.02)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_login_s[df_login_s['tenant']==tenant]['mininterval'].dt.time,
                            y=df_login_s[df_login_s['tenant']==tenant]['success_ct'],
                        mode='lines',
                        name='current_outage_success'),
                        row=1, col=1)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_login_s_p[df_login_s_p['tenant']==tenant]['mininterval']
                             , y=df_login_s_p[df_login_s_p['tenant']==tenant]['success_avg'],
                        mode='markers',
                        name='prior_weeks_success'),
                        row=1, col=1)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_login_f[df_login_f['tenant']==tenant]['mininterval'].dt.time,
                            y=df_login_f[df_login_f['tenant']==tenant]['failure_ct'],
                        mode='markers',
                        name='current_outage_fail'),
                        row=2, col=1)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_login_f_p[df_login_f_p['tenant']==tenant]['mininterval']
                             , y=df_login_f_p[df_login_f_p['tenant']==tenant]['fail_avg'],
                        mode='markers',
                        name='prior_weeks_fail'),
                         row=2, col=1)
    
    fig.update_xaxes(

    title_text = "Time (UTC)", row=2,col=1)

    fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text = "Success Login",
            title_standoff = 25,row=1, col=1)
    
    fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text = "Success Login",
            title_standoff = 25,row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text = "Fail Login",
            title_standoff = 25,row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(
            title_text = "Fail Login",
            title_standoff = 25,row=2, col=1)
    
    
    
    fig.update_layout(height=800, width=1000,
    title="{},{}".format(tenant,single_date))

    fig.show()
```

Again I sorted the df before plotting Thank you

Comment: Why is the x-axis of all 4 graphs not `dt.time`? x-axis is set to shared.

Comment: I tried that also but did not work